# Как сделать церковный календарь?

Tags: java, android

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом как сделать церковный календарь? Чтобы на каждый день снизу высвечивалась строка с именами святых. Сам календарь я могу сделать, а вот как в каждый день прописать информацию? А потом ее оттуда достать? Я только учусь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чет мне кажется обшибка в том, что вы не передаете строку вторым параметром. оберните в кавычки. базе данных пофиг, какой язык, хоть япоснкий. главное передать строку. почитайте SQL синтаксис на всякий случай

Comment: Не задавайте несколько вопросов в одном. Если у вас возник новый вопрос - задайте его отдельно.

Comment: Ну не так же. В левом верхнем углу создать базу. Дайте ей название. Потом поля _id итд и работайте без команд.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну , как вариант, начирикать на компьютере базу данных `SQLite`, где каждый день недели , к примеру, это некий ключ, допустим номер дня в году `193` сегодняшний день. В таблице сегодняшнего дня - праздники, что понятно. По клику на календарь получать дату - перепиливать в день по счету = ключ и по ключу выводить инфу из таблицы или колонки. По архитектуре - сверху календарь, снизу, к примеру , `RecyclerView`. Как то так. Запиливать либо `Room`, либо `SQLiteOpenHelper`. Обычная база данных с обычными запросами по сути.

Или еще удобнее, просто сделать таблицу с праздниками, и у каждого праздника сделать свой ключ, который равняется некому дню недели итд. По клику просто так же выводить ключ в запрос. Так мы получим более гибкую выборку - сортировку итд.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96199/discussion-on-answer-by-----).